# Underline text inside Editbox

Tags: android, android-edittext, underline, editbox

As I enter text in editText it should automatically underline the text I entered. I need like as I continue to enter text in editText it draw like in background.

Can someone help me.

Comment: `I tried by using 9-patch image but image get blurr.` then you need a tutorial on 9 patches.

Answer (score 1):

Use view with 1 dp of height and custom width with green background , inside framelayout over your editText, and handle custom_width same as you are handling image_width.

Answer (score 0):

For *underline effect* in `EditText` you need to add this

```
//initialize edittext before
editText.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```